# Running ant tasks in eclipse with Java 1.8 lead to "JRE version less than 11 is not supported. "

Tags: eclipse, ant

With eclipse I get the following error when I execute an ant task with Java 1.8.

> JRE version less than 11 is not supported.

My "external tool configuration" is configured with "Seperate JRE" Eclipse Adoptium jdk-8.0.352.8-hotspot

Anybody knows how to prevent this restriction?

---

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)
Build id: 20221201-1913

Comment: Looking at the Eclipse code it seems that specifying a class path to a different Ant on the Classpath page of the external tools run configuration might allow this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it running.

- I only need the classes to end up with Java 8.
- Ant itself can run with 11 or higher

Adding source and target with 1.8 did the trick for me in build.xml

> ```
>   <JAVAC destdir="${build.classes.test}" source="1.8" target="1.8">
>         <src path="${src.test}" />
> ```

Afterwards I checked with `javap -v MyStuff.class` and saw Output `major version: 52` which is 1.8

### More background

Here are bugs describing the situation:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=578533
- "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation" - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=579317
- this is the source of the message: https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform/pull/6/commits/89cdd3370482bff681618ca46b6250a0a94b4319

### Further issues

- java task is not running with 1.8

  - The above method worked for the the ant `javac` task. But I had also ant `java` to generate some classes. I ended up with

    `[java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException`
  - Because Ant is running with Java 17 and JAXB classes like `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException` are not included in JDK anymore since Java 11.
  - My workaround is to not use Eclipse for these ant tasks but to use a seperate (old=same we use in jenkins build) ant installation and run tasks from command line. See https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#getBinary
- running ant task with 1.8 leads to `Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again.`

  - "External Tool Configration" -> "JRE" -> "Seperate JRE" switch jdk8 to 17 (or run in the same JRE as the workspace if you have higher jdk there)
  - and because of that this leads to above issues ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Newer versions of Eclipse need that the JRE version be newer than 11 in order for it launch an `Ant` build. Eclipse might use the workspace default JRE to launch your Ant target. You can always override that configuration to use a JRE >=11 for launching Ant builds.

- Go to Run --> External Tools --> External Tools Configurations --> Ant Build --> JRE tab.
- Select Separate JRE radio button and specify a JDK / JRE v11 or
  newer.
- Click Run.

Eclipse will now launch your Ant build with new JRE you have specified. Note that this config change doesn't impact the java class compilation done by Eclipse. Eclipse will continue to use your default workspace JRE to compile your java classes.

Answer (score 2):

According this eclipse thread, since eclipse 2022 version, JDK 11 must be used to launch the build.xml:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=579317

But you can still compile using JDK 1.8 using this trick in the buid.xml :

First: SET your JAVA_HOME in your windows environment to your JDK 1.8 folder

Then add:

```
<property environment="env" />
<javac ... executable="${env.JAVA_HOME}\bin\javac.exe" fork="true" />
```

Then you need to launch the build using JDK >= 11 (you can use the built-in jre of eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, don't use the Ant integration.
Instead create an external tools launch config:

```
Main:
 Location: 
  {installation path}\apache-ant-1.10.13\bin\ant.bat

 Working directory ${workspace_loc:/your_project}

 Arguments:
  -buildfile build.xml

Refresh:
 (X) the entire workspace
 [X] recursively include sub-folders

Environment:
 ANT_HOME  {installation path}\apache-ant-1.10.13
 JAVA_HOME {path_to_your_java_8_directory}

Common:
 [X] Allocate Console (necessary for input)
```

Comment: Good idea.
Just for Working directory I had to take the full path. "Variable references non-existent resource : ${workspace_loc:/your_project}"